# power series quotient of polynomial functions

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I have given $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2x^k$. Why can you now write $g:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ as a quotient of two polynomial functions?

I just know the radius of convergence is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\sqrt[k]{k^2}=1$ and by using the fact for $|x|=1$ is $k^2x^k$ not a null sequence I get convergence for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Start with the geometric series (which holds for $x\in(-1,1))$: $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$$  Now apply the following procedure to both sides: differentiate, multiply by $x$, differentiate again, and multiply by $x$ again.  You should obtain $g(x)$ on the right hand side, and your desired rational function on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: for $\,|x|<1\,$ :

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}\implies$$

$$\implies\frac2{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}=\frac1{x^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2x^k-\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}\;\ldots\ldots$$